# Zero of a continuous function.

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$ . There exists a $t_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(t_0) = 0$ , also $f'(t_0)=0$.

My question is , are these conditions enough to conclude that $f(t) =0 $ for all $t \in [a,b]$ ? And how ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Why should this hold? Even all derivatives vanishing in some point is not enough to deduce that $f$ is constant (if $f$ is analytic, it is enough).

Answer (score 4):

No, for example $y=x^2, [a,b]=[-2;2], t_0=0$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = \left. 2x \right|_0 = 0$, but $f$ does not vanish in $[-1,1]$.